# remove and add classes and click on them

Tags: jquery

```
<div id='menuT'>
<div class='goAct' id='home'>Home</div>
<div class='goPass' id='about'>About</div>
<div class='goPass' id='links'>Links</div>
</div>
```

js

```
$('.goPass').click(function () {
alert ('323');
$('.goAct').removeClass().addClass('goPass');
$(this).removeClass().addClass('goAct');
});
```

Click on `#about` and `#links` works, i.e. classes are switched properly and alert appears. In debug window I see that `#home` becomes `.goPass`.

But click on `#home` doesn't work. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are changing the `classes` for the elements dynamically you have to use `event delegation`,

```
$(document).on('click','.goPass',function (){ 
    alert('hello'); 
});
```

Please read **[here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** to know more about event delegation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), like this:

```
$('#menuT').on('click', '.goPass', function(){
     alert('323');
     $('.goAct').removeClass().addClass('goPass');
     $(this).removeClass().addClass('goAct');
});
```